# How to Unblock UI Thread manually

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin

Hi i have a project in Xamarin.Android Visual Studio that copy some images to sdcard , for reasons i need to make stop in loop without main UI blocked, i already tested some solutions in Async/await but that not really works.

here is my code need to wait for do somethings like show progress bar and etc..

```
void ExportBitmapAsPNG(Bitmap bitmap, string filename)
        {
            var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath + dirPath + "/images", filename);
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();
            progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(5);
            txtLoading.Text = "Loop Loading : " + progressBar.Progress.ToString();
            RunOnUiThread(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
            Console.WriteLine("Image {0} Created", filename);

        }
```

what should i do for that ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap.Compress could be causing some of the freezing as well as your sleep.  I would try something like this

```
async Task ExportBitmapAsPNG(Bitmap bitmap, string filename)
 {
        var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath + dirPath + "/images", filename);
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        stream.Close();
        progressBar.IncrementProgressBy(5);
        txtLoading.Text = "Loop Loading : " + progressBar.Progress.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Image {0} Created", filename);

    }
```